# Is it possible to change the style (font size, font type, etc) for multiple tables in a powerpoint presentation?

Tags: font-size, microsoft-powerpoint

The Slide master in MS Powerpoint lets the user set font size and font type and then, if any change needs to occur, lets the user apply the change consistently across all slides.

I was wondering if such a facility also exists in MS Powerpoint for centrally controlling the font size and font type for all text in multiple tables in a powerpoint presentation?

Answer (score 1):

You can not centrally controll the font size, but you can replace a font type with another in a particular slide or throughout the presentation using the 'Replace font' tool in the editing section in the 'Home' tab.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely you can change the style of multiple tables in PowerPoint presentation. Firstly, You have to set the Slide master as per your requirement such as setting the font size, color, font type whatever the designing you want in the whole slides you can set them in the slide master and then save them. PowerPoint apply all the changes in all the slides.

I have found an amazing site on Google its www[dot]slideteam[dot]net. You can read more PowerPoint tutorials from here.